# What is the best way to debug a client-server app in netbeans?

Tags: java, multithreading, debugging, netbeans

How can I debug my client-server app ?

It's the first time that I debug a multi-thread app.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Like you do with every other application: breakpoints, step by step, lots of logs and System.out.println();